# Zend_Auth_Adapter_Ldap account canonical form problem

Tags: zend-framework, authentication, ldap

I've been testing authentication against an LDAP server using Zend's LDAP authentication adapter (Zend_Auth_Adapter_Ldap). I have been able to successfully authenticate with the following options:

```
"host" => "localhost",
"port" => "389",
"useStartTls" => "false",
"bindRequiresDn" => "false",
"baseDn" => "OU=foo,DC=bar,DC=com",
"accountDomainName" => "foobar.com",
"accountDomainNameShort" => "FOOBAR",
"accountCanonicalForm"   => "4"
```

However, I have been running into some problems with the accountCanonicalForm option.

Of the 3 different account canonical forms I have been testing with (2, 3, 4), I have only been able to successfully authenticate with a value of 3 or 4. Changing solely the accountCanonicalForm value in the LDAP server options to 2 makes the server spit back an "Invalid Credentials" error.

[Here's a link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.adapter.ldap.html) giving a better explanation of what I'm talking about:

Bottom line is that I would like to know why it doesn't successfully authenticate with 2 as the accountCanonicalForm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in the [options here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.adapter.ldap.html#zend.auth.adapter.ldap.server-options)

> Values are as follows: 2 for traditional username style names (e.g., alice), 3 for backslash-style names (e.g., FOO\alice) or 4 for principal style usernames (e.g., alice@foo.net).

Your directory obviously does not work with traditional username styles.